# 3D polygons in R

Tags: r

I have a three dimensional point cloud (x, y, z). I want to generate a polygon from these points. As a first step I have considered only the plane (x, y) and there I have applied the following algorithm to generate a polygon (graphically).

```
library(sp)
library(deldir)
#set.seed(25)

cloudOfPointsX <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
cloudOfPointsY <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
cloudOfPointsZ <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)

listOfPoints = data.frame(cloudOfPointsX, cloudOfPointsY, cloudOfPointsZ)
plot(listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsX, listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsY)
plot(listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsX, listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsY)

while(nrow(listOfPoints) > 2){
  
  pMaxX = listOfPoints[which.max(listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsX),]
  listOfPoints <- listOfPoints[-(match(pMaxX[1], listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsX)),]
  pMaxY = listOfPoints[which.max(listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsY),]
  listOfPoints <- listOfPoints[-(match(pMaxY[2], listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsY)),]
  pMinX = listOfPoints[which.min(listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsX),]
  listOfPoints <- listOfPoints[-(match(pMinX[1], listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsX)),]
  pMinY = listOfPoints[which.min(listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsY),]
  listOfPoints <- listOfPoints[-(match(pMinY[2], listOfPoints$cloudOfPointsY)),]
  
  polygon(x = c(pMinY[1], pMaxX[1], pMaxY[1], pMinX[1]), y = c(pMinY[2], pMaxX[2], pMaxY[2], pMinX[2]), col = "magenta")
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aGil.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyY9j.png)

But I want the polygon I got to be 3D, and therefore also have the z-value of each point. How can I keep the same algorithm and get a 3D polygon? Or how can I get a 3D polygon from a point cloud?

The polygon that I will obtain will be used to be able to make intersections with axes, lines and other polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a 3D triangle in R, you can use the `triangles3d` function of the **rgl** package:

```r
library(rgl)
cloudOfPointsX <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
cloudOfPointsY <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
cloudOfPointsZ <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
pts <- cbind(cloudOfPointsX, cloudOfPointsY, cloudOfPointsZ)

triangles3d(pts[1:3, ], color = "red")
```

This plots an interactive triangle.

I don't understand why you take 25 because this is not a multiple of 3.

But regarding your last point, there's no function in **rgl** to compute intersections. What are the intersections you want more precisely? Intersection between an edge of the triangle and a line?

---

## Edit: 2.5D Delaunay triangulation

After reading your comment I think you want an elevated Delaunay triangulation. You can do that with the **delaunay** package.

```r
library(delaunay)

set.seed(666L)
cloudOfPointsX <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
cloudOfPointsY <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
cloudOfPointsZ <- runif(25, min=0, max=100)
pts <- cbind(cloudOfPointsX, cloudOfPointsY, cloudOfPointsZ)

# compute Delaunay triangulation
del <- delaunay(pts, elevation = TRUE)

# plot
mesh <- del[["mesh"]]
library(rgl)
open3d(windowRect = c(50, 50, 562, 562))
shade3d(mesh, color = "limegreen")
wire3d(mesh)
```

[image]

Comment: From a three-dimensional point cloud I have to obtain a three-dimensional polygon such as 3D land elevation models. I would need to obtain a polygon with which we can make an intersection with a vertical rectangle

Comment: @AntonioC I think you mean an elevated Delaunay triangulation. Right?